# grunt.file write/copy with permissions

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy, gruntfile

Is there a way to specify the permissions of a file during a grunt.file.copy(...), except using the 'fs.chmod' after copy has finished?

I will have to require the whole 'fs' module otherwise, just for changing the permissions. Will it be a lot of overhead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grunt.file.copy` does not provide any option for that, unfortunately.

But the grunt `copy` task (from `grunt-contrib-copy`) has an option for that (`options.mode`, see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#mode).

Comment: will `grunt-contrib-copy` work in a consistent way across linux and windows machines?

Comment: It should, it uses Node 'fs' behind the scene.